# Creating separate feature branch and commiting to Git - How to ensure local git repo shows status of feature instead of origin/develop?

Tags: git

Checking out the feature branch into my local machine, the command git status shows origin/master. I cloned from feature repo only. How do I make sure the local git repo shows status of feature instead of origin/develop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i was able to solve my question using the above two approaches.

1. Git clone url
2. Git branch branchname
3. git checkout
4. git add file1.java
5. git commit -m 'commiting latest changes for jiraxxx'
6. git push --reset-head feature/branchname

Thanks ranjeet and daly for ur answers. Upvoting ur answers.

Answer (score 3):

To checkout an **existing branch** run:

`git checkout existingBranchName`

To create and checkout a **new branch** run:

`git checkout -b newBranchName`

To pull/push to **any branch** run:

`git [pull|push] origin branchName`

Note that pushing and pulling requires you to be on the branch being pushed or pulled. (Unless you use the `:` syntax.) When pushing a new branch for the first time git will set up a local `origin/newBranchName` pointer to track the remote branch, and associate it with `newBranchName` on your machine.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: git branch is not showing any feature branch. existing branch is displayed as "master". however, i have created new branch in Git repository using GIT Repo UI. can i clone that repo instead of checkout?

Comment: Cloning copies an entire repo from a remote server to your machine. Checkout switches between branches in a local repo. If your local machine only has `master` but the remote repo has some branch `branchnameX`, then you need to check out a new branch locally with the name `branchnameX` and then pull from the remote repository.

Answer (score 2):

Add all your commits in feature branch for push. Make sure you are working in feature branch by

`git checkout feature`

While pushing files to git, use

`git push origin feature`

Hope this will work for you.